# Install Istio using a Docker Image?

Tags: docker, istio, spinnaker

Currently, the only officially supported way to install Istio is to use Istio's own CLI (`istioctl`). Does anyone know if there is a way I can use a docker image to install it on a given cluster? This may seem convoluted, but the ultimate point is to get it to work through Spinnaker.

Anyways, this is what I came up with for the Dockerfile.

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl
RUN mkdir -p /scripts
COPY DownloadIstio.sh /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts
RUN chmod +x DownloadIstio.sh
RUN ./DownloadIstio.sh
WORKDIR istio-1.13.2/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["./istioctl", "install", "-y"]
```

It builds, but if I just run in locally say `docker run <image name` I run into `localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s`. Since I'm not too well versed with this stuff, I was wondering if there was a way to run this image using a kubernetes manifest yaml that authenticated to the local cluster. Any ideas of getting something like this to work would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`istioctl` require kubeconfig to function properly. You have to `COPY` your kubeconfig into the image.

Minimal working image Dockerfile would be

```
FROM debian:stable-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -
COPY ./config /kubeconfig
WORKDIR istio-1.13.2/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["./istioctl", "-c", "/kubeconfig", "install", "-y"]
```

However, including your kubeconfig in resulting image is a security concern.